# Bug? Config error? geth error: admin.addPeer is unsuccessful

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, parity, javascript, peers

I am trying to get a few nodes to talk to each other over a private network - two Parity and then add in one geth.  Two of them talk just fine, but their enodes are in the chain spec file (Parity.)

The geth node isn't connecting.

When I use the js console, I get:

```
> admin.addPeer("enode://3.......@<ip>:<port>") 
true
```

So that looks good.  But then when I test, it goes like this:

```
> admin.peers

[]
```

And that's much less good.

Any ideas?  Is there something I need to do to tell geth to connect to this private network *other* than give it the initial "init" parameters?

Comment: I have the similar problem here. I have checked by telnet to required ports to server which is 100% opened. And both geth servers runs geth individually without obvious problem.

I believe that it may be a very tricky point we have to set. Otherwise, it must be a bug.

Comment: At least I don't feel so alone anymore!